# Sql server data export to csv Limit to 100k records at a time

Tags: sql-server

I'm using sql statements to query data from multiple tables and exporting them into a single csv file, then importing that file somewhere else. I want to limit the csv file to about 100k records at a time. Also, I can't split up id numbers from a field. e.g. All the rows for Cust_id 1 need to be in the same csv file. Not split between 2 files.
Is there a way to do this by adding to the statement used to select the data, or in the export function in sql server?  Thank you

```
select
   [Customer Name] = c.customername
  ,[Customer ID] = c.id
  ,[Item Purchased] = o.itemname
  ,[Item Number] = o.itemNum
  ,[Item Description] = o.itemDesc
from dbo.mystore.customermstr c
join dbo.mystore.items o 
    on c.id = o.customerid
where c.status = 'true';
```

The results return 1,000,000 rows. Export to csv files of approx 100,000 rows each. csv filename format cusexp_{datetime}_{iterationNumber}. Don't break up same c.id between multiple files. So in this case I'd have around 10 csv files

Comment: "*Is there a way to do this by adding to the statement used to select the data*" - And that statement is?

Comment: Please show the schema, sample data and your query

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry. I thought it was in there. Say I'm gathering all data for customer orders. When I export to csv, I can't have customer number 'x' have some orders in 1 csv file and some in another. I need them all to be in the same file, while also keeping the total record count to around 100k when exported and auto incrementing the csv file until all records are exported.

Comment: "*sorry. I thought it was in there.*" - The query is still not there, can you please add it?

Comment: sorry, i can't post the actual script as it's very long and has proprietary information in it.

Comment: You can obfuscate the code before adding it to your question. Otherwise there's not much advise that can be offered.

Comment: Thanks again for getting back to me.

Comment: OK. Just updated the original post with a sql statement. A bit of a simplified version, but it produces the same result. I hope this helps. Thank you again everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are running your SQL queries manually in e.g. SSMS and then exporting the output from the Results pane after each query.  Here is an approach you could try.

1. Run your query with a `TOP` clause and an `ORDER BY` clause, like this:

   ```
   select TOP (100000) WITH TIES
      [Customer Name] = c.customername
     ,[Customer ID] = c.id
     ,[Item Purchased] = o.itemname
     ,[Item Number] = o.itemNum
     ,[Item Description] = o.itemDesc
   from dbo.mystore.customermstr c
   join dbo.mystore.items o 
       on c.id = o.customerid
   where c.status = 'true'
   ORDER BY c.id ASC;
   ```

   The `TOP ... WITH TIES` together with `ORDER BY` ensures that the last customer in the batch will have all their data included in the resulting set.
2. Export the data and remember the last `[Customer ID]` value.
3. Edit the query again by adding a condition to the `WHERE` clause and run again:

   ```
   select TOP (100000) WITH TIES
      [Customer Name] = c.customername
     ,[Customer ID] = c.id
     ,[Item Purchased] = o.itemname
     ,[Item Number] = o.itemNum
     ,[Item Description] = o.itemDesc
   from dbo.mystore.customermstr c
   join dbo.mystore.items o 
       on c.id = o.customerid
   where c.status = 'true'
     AND c.id > the_last_Customer_ID_from_previous_run
   ORDER BY c.id ASC;
   ```

   This way the next data batch will start after the previous batch's last customer.
4. Export the data and remember the last `[Customer ID]` value again.
5. Change the Customer ID value in the filtering condition and run again.
6. Repeat 4 & 5 until no more rows is returned (or until the row set returned contains less than 100,000 rows).

Comment: Thank you. That will help reduce time some and make it a little cleaner.